# Prevent SVG CSS bleeding

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

So basically I have a webpage with two SVGs. On click the chosen SVG will be visible.

Problem: If a SVG with viewport *0 0 20 20* is loaded first and has a stroke-width of 2 and then you load the other SVG with viewport *0 0 2000 2000*, the stroke-width of the first one is inherited to the second one. The 2nd one has now a stroke-width of 2 instead of 200.

This is how the containers are:

```
<div class="clearView-container">
  // svg 2
</div>
<div class="techView-container" style="display: none;">
  // svg 1
</div>
```

**svg1:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="273.263mm" height="210.784mm" viewBox="-49.35 -56.0421 136.632 105.392">

<defs>
 <style type="text/css">
 .pen_style1 {stroke: #000000;stroke-width: 0.25;}
 .pen_style3 {stroke: #c6c6c6;stroke-width: 0.125;stroke-dasharray: 1, 0.5}
 .pen_style4 {stroke: #ff0000;stroke-width: 0.125;stroke-dasharray: 0.2, 0.5, 1, 0.5}
 .cos {stroke: #0037a0;}
 .hiddenLine {     display: none;   }
 </style>
</defs>
```

**svg2:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="127.46mm" height="104.6mm" viewBox="-3214 -2698 6373 5230">

<defs>
 <style type="text/css">
 .pen_style1 {stroke: #000000;stroke-width: 25;}
 .pen_style3 {stroke: #c6c6c6;stroke-width: 12.5;stroke-dasharray: 100, 50}
 .pen_style4 {stroke: #ff0000;stroke-width: 12.5;stroke-dasharray: 20, 50, 100, 50}
 .cos {stroke: #0037a0;}
 .hiddenLine {     display: none;   }
 </style>
</defs>
```

And now the SVG in the `clearView-container` gets the properties of the one from the `techView-container` if this one (svg1) is loaded first.

**Is there a way to prevent the `<defs>` of the two SVGs to "bleed through"?**

Comment: Do you need these elements to be inlined in your document? If so, why?

Comment: @Kaiido yes, because the svg is generated by a server. the pen_styles can be different for each svg for every picture displayed. It depends on the users settings.

Comment: No I mean why do you need them to be in your document as <svg ....> (i.e "*inlined*") Can you display them simply as <img src="path_to/your/server">? If not why?

Comment: It's not ideal, but if you're generating the SVGs server side, you could work around this by adding a unique string into the classes so each SVG has unique styles.

Comment: @Kaiido oh sorry missunderstanding here. It has to be a svg, because there are many transformations happening on the client-side after the generation (such as: switching on/off some lines, moving parts of it.) I can't change the entire "ecosystem" It works well but wasn't designed for two svgs on one page and this is what I have to do now.

Comment: @DBS That is an option but I hope to find a client side solution. I will look into this if there is no other way. Thx so far.

Comment: What kind of interactions? This is very important for us to know this so we can provide the best solution for you. If it's all js based, then you can load your svg image in an iframe and still execute js there, with no leak to the main doc. If it requires some CSS link form the main doc to the svg, then indeed you must have the svg inlined, and then as a last resort you may consider editing the stylesheet of your SVGStyleElement so that all its rules be more specific.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add an ID to the SVGs themselves and make the CSS more specific? e.g. `#svg1 .pen_style1`? I don't think you can do this without making any changes to either the SVGs, or how the SVGs are loaded. The browser will always parse all CSS before applying it, so a second inline SVG's styles will always overwrite duplicate identifiers further up the document.

Comment: @Kaiido interactions like I told you: switching on/off some lines, moving parts of it. Everything is based on JS/TS. I think I'm going to go with the iframe idea. Seems the easiest one. Afaik the SVG it self does not nead any CSS from the main doc.

Comment: @DBS That would be my second try then. If the other one fails. Thanks to both of you so far.

Comment: Have you considered styling the SVGs using attributes on the svg elements rather than using css classes? If you have many paths with the same style you can wrap them in a `<g>` and add the attributes to that. May not work semantically depending on your use case but potential fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case an answer is needed by someone. This is how I ended up doing it.
I get the svg from a server as string. Than I used @DBSs solution with the IDs (can't do it server-side so here it is:)

```
function _injectCustomCSS (svg: string): string {
  const newID = 'id' + MathLib.hashCode(svg);
  const replaceStr = /.pen/g;
  const svgDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svg, 'image/svg+xml');
  svgDoc.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].setAttribute('id', newID);
  svgDoc.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].textContent = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].textContent.replace(replaceStr, '#' + newID + '>.pen');

  /* ... */
  return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgDoc);
};
```